# Unable to use JMockit with OpenJDK 1.7

Tags: junit, java, jmockit

While trying to use JMockit (1.21) with JUnit (4.8) test cases I ran into issue with OpenJDK (1.7). I'm using Eclipse. After searching on SO, I found the solution about adding '*-javaagent:path/to/JMockit/jar*' argument to JVM and putting JMockit dependency before JUnit in maven. But after adding that argument, my test won't run and instead I get following error. **Did anyone have this issue and how did you solve it?** It works if I use OracleJDK but I'm looking for solution where it runs with OpenJDK.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000051cfbbe8, pid=9268, tid=2272
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0) (build 1.7.0-45-asmurthy_2014_01_10_19_46-b00)
# Java VM: Dynamic Code Evolution 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b06 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x6bbe8]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000000270c000):  VMThread [stack: 0x00000000074e0000,0x00000000075e0000] [id=2272]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x00000007fae04720
RSP=0x00000000075df190, RBP=0x00000000523a16d8, RSI=0x0000000002abe2b0, RDI=0x00000000523a16e0
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x0000000000000100, R10=0x0000000000041999, R11=0x0000000008eab1f0
R12=0x000000000270c000, R13=0x00000007fb208040, R14=0x0000000000000001, R15=0x00000000000003d8
RIP=0x0000000051cfbbe8, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000000075df190)
0x00000000075df190:   00000007fb208050 0000000002abe200
0x00000000075df1a0:   00000007fb208040 000000000270c000
0x00000000075df1b0:   00000000523a16e0 0000000051e0ecbc
0x00000000075df1c0:   0000000000000000 00000000523a16d8
0x00000000075df1d0:   0000000002abe2b0 000000000270c000
0x00000000075df1e0:   00000000521ea7b8 0000000052450100
0x00000000075df1f0:   0000000000000000 00000000521ea7a0
0x00000000075df200:   0000000000001000 00000000075df1e0
0x00000000075df210:   0000000000000100 0000000000000000
0x00000000075df220:   00000000073158d8 00000000000003d8
0x00000000075df230:   00000000073158d8 0000000002701ac0
0x00000000075df240:   00000000073154f0 0000000051e74dc7
0x00000000075df250:   00000000026c3de0 0000000000000001
0x00000000075df260:   0000000002abe2b0 0000000007315500
0x00000000075df270:   0000000007315500 00000000073154f0
0x00000000075df280:   0000000002701ac0 0000000051e74072 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000051cfbbe8)
0x0000000051cfbbc8:   cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 48 89 5c 24 08 57 48 83
0x0000000051cfbbd8:   ec 20 48 8b 05 17 20 69 00 48 8b 0d c0 e5 68 00
0x0000000051cfbbe8:   48 63 18 e8 60 c3 fa ff 33 ff 48 85 db 7e 37 66
0x0000000051cfbbf8:   0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 48 8b 05 f1 1f 69 00 48 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDX=0x00000007fae04720 is an oop
{instance class} 
 - klass: {other class}
RSP=0x00000000075df190 is an unknown value
RBP=0x00000000523a16d8 is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000002abe2b0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000026c7000
RDI=0x00000000523a16e0 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000100 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000041999 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000008eab1f0 is an unknown value
R12=0x000000000270c000 is an unknown value
R13=0x00000007fb208040 is an oop
{instance class} 
 - klass: {other class}
R14=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R15=0x00000000000003d8 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x00000000074e0000,0x00000000075e0000],  sp=0x00000000075df190,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x6bbe8]

VM_Operation (0x0000000002abe2b0): RedefineClasses, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x00000000026c7000


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000000739c800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6668, stack(0x0000000007c60000,0x0000000007d60000)]
  0x000000000739b000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5620, stack(0x0000000007aa0000,0x0000000007ba0000)]
  0x0000000007379800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9832, stack(0x00000000078c0000,0x00000000079c0000)]
  0x0000000007370000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7516, stack(0x0000000007680000,0x0000000007780000)]
  0x00000000026c7000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=6580, stack(0x00000000029c0000,0x0000000002ac0000)]

Other Threads:
=>0x000000000270c000 VMThread [stack: 0x00000000074e0000,0x00000000075e0000] [id=2272]

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x00000000026c3e60] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x000000000270c000
[0x00000000026c4360] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x00000000026c7000
[0x00000000026c4b60] RedefineClasses_lock - owner thread: 0x00000000026c7000

Heap
 def new generation   total 118016K, used 21035K [0x000000067ae00000, 0x0000000682e00000, 0x00000006fae00000)
  eden space 104960K,  20% used [0x000000067ae00000, 0x000000067c28af18, 0x0000000681480000)
  from space 13056K,   0% used [0x0000000681480000, 0x0000000681480000, 0x0000000682140000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x0000000682140000, 0x0000000682140000, 0x0000000682e00000)
 tenured generation   total 262144K, used 0K [0x00000006fae00000, 0x000000070ae00000, 0x00000007fae00000)
   the space 262144K,   0% used [0x00000006fae00000, 0x00000006fae00000, 0x00000006fae00200, 0x000000070ae00000)
 compacting perm gen  total 21248K, used 4129K [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fc2c0000, 0x0000000800000000)
   the space 21248K,  19% used [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fb208478, 0x00000007fb208600, 0x00000007fc2c0000)
No shared spaces configured.

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000005e60000,0x0000000006a90000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000002a89000

Polling page: 0x0000000000150000

Code Cache  [0x0000000002da0000, 0x0000000003010000, 0x0000000005da0000)
 total_blobs=187 nmethods=0 adapters=156 free_code_cache=48761Kb largest_free_block=49932032

Compilation events (0 events):
No events

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 1.210 Thread 0x00000000026c7000 Threw 0x000000067c036fa0 at C:\openjdk\jdk7u\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp:347
Event: 1.211 Thread 0x00000000026c7000 Threw 0x000000067c03ae78 at C:\openjdk\jdk7u\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 1.212 Thread 0x00000000026c7000 Threw 0x000000067c045f10 at C:\openjdk\jdk7u\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 1.213 Thread 0x00000000026c7000 Threw 0x000000067c057398 at C:\openjdk\jdk7u\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 1.214 Thread 0x00000000026c7000 Threw 0x000000067c066510 at C:\openjdk\jdk7u\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 1.215 Thread 0x00000000026c7000 Threw 0x000000067c072ac0 at C:\openjdk\jdk7u\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 1.216 Thread 0x00000000026c7000 Threw 0x000000067c084678 at C:\openjdk\jdk7u\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 1.217 Thread 0x00000000026c7000 Threw 0x000000067c08c7b0 at C:\openjdk\jdk7u\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 1.218 Thread 0x00000000026c7000 Threw 0x000000067c0934a8 at C:\openjdk\jdk7u\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 1.218 Thread 0x00000000026c7000 Threw 0x000000067c09cac8 at C:\openjdk\jdk7u\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244

Events (10 events):
Event: 1.215 loading class 0x0000000008956520 done
Event: 1.216 loading class 0x0000000008959de0
Event: 1.216 loading class 0x0000000008959de0 done
Event: 1.217 loading class 0x0000000008ea91d0
Event: 1.217 loading class 0x0000000008ea91d0 done
Event: 1.218 loading class 0x0000000008d643e0
Event: 1.218 loading class 0x0000000008d643e0 done
Event: 1.218 loading class 0x0000000008958d20
Event: 1.218 loading class 0x0000000008958d20 done
Event: 1.219 Executing VM operation: RedefineClasses


Dynamic libraries:
0x000000013f7c0000 - 0x000000013f7f1000     S:\OpenJDK\bin\javaw.exe
0x0000000076ef0000 - 0x0000000077099000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000076cb0000 - 0x0000000076dcf000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefcde0000 - 0x000007fefce4b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x0000000074990000 - 0x0000000074a19000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SYSFER.DLL
0x000007feff0f0000 - 0x000007feff1cb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefed40000 - 0x000007fefeddf000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007fefe660000 - 0x000007fefe67f000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefefc0000 - 0x000007feff0ed000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x0000000076df0000 - 0x0000000076eea000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fefe270000 - 0x000007fefe2d7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefe360000 - 0x000007fefe36e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007fefe370000 - 0x000007fefe43a000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefb460000 - 0x000007fefb654000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.18837_none_fa3b1e3d17594757\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007fefee30000 - 0x000007fefeea1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007fefe630000 - 0x000007fefe65e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefeeb0000 - 0x000007fefefb9000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x0000000052420000 - 0x00000000524f2000     S:\OpenJDK\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x0000000051c90000 - 0x000000005241e000     S:\OpenJDK\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fef82b0000 - 0x000007fef82b9000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007fefede0000 - 0x000007fefee2d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007feff1d0000 - 0x000007feff1d8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fefaca0000 - 0x000007fefacdb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
0x00000000770c0000 - 0x00000000770c7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x000007feece20000 - 0x000007feece2f000     S:\OpenJDK\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x000007fee0320000 - 0x000007fee0348000     S:\OpenJDK\jre\bin\java.dll
0x000007fee6ee0000 - 0x000007fee6f03000     S:\OpenJDK\jre\bin\instrument.dll
0x000007fee06e0000 - 0x000007fee06f5000     S:\OpenJDK\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fef1f90000 - 0x000007fef20b5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -javaagent:S:\.m2\org\jmockit\jmockit\1.21\jmockit-1.21.jar -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 
java_command: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner -version 3 -port 61294 -testLoaderClass org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader -loaderpluginname org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime -classNames com.examples.JMockitTest
java_command: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner -version 3 -port 61294 -testLoaderClass org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader -loaderpluginname org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime -classNames com.examples.JMockitTest
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\Common\Java5.0\jre
PATH=C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\Clearquest\cqcli\bin;C:\PERL51001\Perl\site\bin;C:\PERL51001\Perl\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Application Virtualization Client;C:\Program Files (x86)\java\jre6\bin\;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Perforce;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\common;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

Thanks

Comment: No one has encountered this issue?

Comment: Hi, just in case, I got something like this, and was due to be mocking File which the JVM needs (actually it can happen with some other classes that the JVM needs). Could it be your case?